# How to use team foundation server in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am completely new to team foundation server and trying to understand how it works. Here are some questions which I've been struggling with for a while:

1- Once a team project has been created, how can solutions be attached to it?

2- Is any team member able to attach code or it must be an administrator?

3- How can code from other team members be accessed once it has been submitted?

4- Are there any recommended settings for tfs in a local server?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer each of you questions

1. You can add a solution to your Team Project either my right-clicking the solution node in the Solution Explorer and selecting *Add Solution to Source Control...* or through the Source Control Explorer by placing the solution in your workspace and clicking the *Add Items to Folder* icon in the toolbar. You now have a Pending Change for adding the files which can be committed to the Team Project when you are ready for it. The commit is done from Pending Changes in the Team Explorer.
2. Normally any member of the contributor TFS group for the Team Project can add code, but this can be customized as needed.
3. Once code has been committed to the Team Project (through Pending Changes), another team member can see the code at Get Latest to have it locally. Both team members can now work on the same code locally and commit changes when they want the others to see those changes too.
4. I am not completely sure what you mean here. There are recommendations to what hardware is needed for a local TFS installation. Those can be seen here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements

Answer (score 0):

1. You just need to create the solution in VS and then add the solution in source control under that team project.
2. It's based on the **permission**. Usually the user just need to add in the **contributors** group.
   [image]

3.The can veiw the code in the solution explorer of VS, just need to do the get latest option. 
[image]

4.Can explain more clear related to this one, if you mean as a user you just need to configure a mapping workspace, as a tfs admin the settings are based on your requerment.

If you are really new to TFS, suggest you read this particular MSDN link: [Use Team Foundation Version Control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/overview)